Flow of Nutfah in woman body
وقال ابن أبي حاتم : حدثنا أحمد بن سنان ، حدثنا أبو معاوية عن الأعمش ، عن خيثمة قال : قال عبد الله يعني : ابن مسعود إن النطفة إذا وقعت في الرحم ، طارت في كل شعر وظفر ، فتمكث أربعين يوما ، ثم تتحدر في الرحم  فتكون علقة .
What is the authenticity of this hadith mentioned in Tafsir ibn Kathir in Sura 23 ayat 14. Probably it is Against observation.Help me kindly

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the &QA site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please add a link to Tafsir ibn Kathir or at least the information on the context, i.e. the verse that was drawn out. Also since the statement here is of 'Abdullah ibn Mas'ud it isn't strictly speaking a hadith.

I Have already given the reference.It is in Tafsir ibn kasir from Sura 23 verse 14.And yes it is The Statement of Ibn Masud RA

https://quran.com/al-muminun/14 here is The link.In this website you can check ibn kasir.But must check in Arabic one as The English one is just a short version

Is this a hadith, an athar or in other words can we attribute it to the prophet () or is it an ijtihad of ibn Mas'ud?

وقال ابن أبي حاتم : حدثنا أحمد بن سنان ، حدثنا أبو معاوية عن الأعمش ، عن خيثمة قال : قال عبد الله يعني : ابن مسعود إن النطفة إذا وقعت في الرحم ، طارت في كل شعر وظفر ، فتمكث أربعين يوما ، ثم تتحدر في الرحم فتكون علقة .
Ibn Abi Hatim said: Ahmad ibn Sinan told us, Abu Mu'awiyah told us, on the authority of Al-A’mash, on the authority of Khaithamah, who said: 'Abdullah, meaning Ibn Mas'ud, said: When the sperm falls into the womb, it flies into every hair and nail, and remains for forty days, then descends into the womb and becomes a clot.

As stated in my comment above, strictly speaking, the quote isn't a hadith since the statement came from Abdullah ibn Mas'ud, who didn't attribute it to the prophet ().
Nevertheless, classical scholars would say that to make such a statement ibn Mas'ud should have got prior knowledge from a person who received a revelation so that he wouldn't bring it up from his own.
This is the reason why it is often mentioned in the context of other ahadith on the topic such as the sahih hadith which was reported on ibn Mas'ud's authority by both al-Bukhari and Muslim and elsewhere.
Having that said, I'd like to add that I'd rather regard the statement as what it actually is "an interpretation of ibn Mas'ud" on the sahih hadith that was reported on his authority, based on his understanding. Why? Since the only correct or we might say authentic information in his statement is about the duration of stay in womb and that the next phase is becoming a clot.
Authenticity of the statement
we may safely say that the Scholars ibn Abi Hatim, Ahmad ibn Sinan, abu Mu'awiyah a-Darir, al-'Amash, Khaitamah ibn 'Abd ar-Rahman are regarded as trustworthy narrators.
We can also confirm that 'Abdurrahman ibn abi Hatim was a student of Ahmad ibn Sinan and ibn Sinan was a student of MU'awiyah a-Darir (you may find this confirmed in a-Dhahabi's Siyar 'alaam an-Nubalaa').
We can further confirm that abu Mu'awiyah a-Darir is one of the best reporters of the hadith of al-'Amash (when it comes to other of his teachers he was less reliable). Al-'Amash was a student of 'Abdurrahman ibn Khaithamah.
A-Dhahabi however, mentioned that it was reported that 'Aburrahaman ibn Khaithamah stated that he had met 13 sahabi all of them had grey hair, he further declined that Kaithamah has met 'Abdullah ibn Mas'ud in his Siyar 'Alaam an-Nubalaa' and also in Tareekh al-Islam (see here). Arabic Wikipeadia starts the article saying that he was a companion of ibn Mas'ud, but when it come sto naming the sahabah he has met among the 18 names that were also mentioned in al-Mizzi's Tahdeeb al-Kamal there's no mentioning of ibn Mas'ud.
Ibn Hajar in his Tahdeeb at-Tahdeeb (see here) mentioned the following: 'Abdullah ibn Ahmad reported from his father that Khaithamah didn't hear ibn Masu'd, further abu Zur'aa stated Khaithamah from 'Umar () are mursal reports (this should be fine since it is only reported by ibn Sa'ad that Kaithamah heard his son 'Abdullah ibn 'Umar's () oral reports), ibn al-Qattan however, claimed some doubt about him hearing 'Aishah (). See also here a summary of all statements made in different books in Arabic.
From a technical perspective, the narratorchain seems ok, the only disconnection is between ibn Mas'ud and Khaithamah, but the latter could have heard ibn Mas'ud's hadith via other sources. My last link quotes a statement of Ahmad ibn Hanbal, saying that he reported via al-Aswad (ibn Yazid) the hadith of ibn Mas'ud. This confirms that he used to practice irsaal (leaving out an intermediate narrator), which in such a case could be fine, since he is an early tabi'i and the son and grand son of a sahabi.

The chain of transmission is not connected to the Prophet ﷺ.
It may very well just be the opinion or belief of Ibn Masud.
Nothing about this belief is binding unto others muslims, you are free to accept or reject it unless you can prove it authentically goes back to the Prophet ﷺ.
The companions had various views about the world which go against modern science and many of these views were simply products of the environment they lived in. Ibn Abbas for example believed that pearls were formed due to rainfall.
